# C# string splitting

Tags: c#, string

If I have a string: `str1|str2|str3|srt4` and parse it with `|` as a delimiter. My output would be `str1 str2 str3 str4`.

But if I have a string: `str1||str3|str4` output would be `str1 str3 str4`. What I'm looking for my output to be like is `str1 null/blank str3 str4`.

I hope this makes sense.

```
string createText = "srt1||str3|str4";
string[] txt = createText.Split(new[] { '|', ',' },
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    //Console.WriteLine("{0} already exists.", path);
    File.Delete(path);
    // write to file.

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("str1:{0}",txt[0]);
        sw.WriteLine("str2:{0}",txt[1]);
        sw.WriteLine("str3:{0}",txt[2]);
        sw.WriteLine("str4:{0}",txt[3]);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
str1:str1
str2:str3
str3:str4
str4:"blank"
```

Thats not what i'm looking for. This is what I would like to code:

```
str1:str1
str2:"blank"
str3:str3
str4:str4
```

Comment: You should look up what the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries flag does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [Quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
String [] parts = new Regex("[|]+").split("str1|str2|str3|srt4");
```

The "+" gets rid of it.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) :
"+" The plus sign indicates that there is one or more of the preceding element. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on, but not "ac".

Form [msdn: The Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) methods are similar to the String.Split method, except Split splits the string at a delimiter determined by a regular expression instead of a set of characters. The input string is split as many times as possible. If pattern is not found in the input string, the return value contains one element whose value is the original input string.

Additional wish can be done with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            String[] parts = "str1||str2|str3".Replace(@"||", "|\"blank\"|").Split(@"|");

            foreach (string s in parts)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a "cool" way to use `Regex`, but it's a very round-about solution to the question that was posed.  The OP simply wanted to preserve empty segments, and the `Split` function does this by default -- unless you pass the option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.  So the OP could have solved the original problem by simply removing the unneeded option from the call to `Split` in the original example code.  Building and compiling a regular expression is way more overhead (and way more complication) than is needed for this case.

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```
str.Split('|')
```

Without `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` passed, it'll work as you want.

Comment: I misread the question, what I thought OP want is what he doesn't want..haha.sorry I'll change vote-down to vote-up in 8 minutes because SO locks my vote function now :(

Comment: SO tells me "You last voted on this answer 14 mins ago Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited". So I can't vote to your answer until you edit it? Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 8):

this should do the trick...

```
string s = "str1||str3|str4";
string[] parts = s.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
string result = "str1||str3|srt4";
List<string> parsedResult = result.Split('|').Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "null" : x).ToList();
```

when using the `Split()` the resulting string in the array will be empty (not null). In this example i have tested for it and replaced it with the actual word `null` so you can see how to substitute in another value.